# PHP - limiting the output of a plugin

Tags: php, plugins, limiting

I'm using a plugin titled "WP Recent Links" which I first learned about via Eric Meyer's site. Eric uses to display a Link Log within his site and I'm doing the same on my test site -  http://matala.jorgeledesma.net/ but I'm running into a little situation and that is that I don't know how to limit the output either on the sidebar or the actual page - http://matala.jorgeledesma.net/recent-links/

My goal is to have it echo only the first 5 entries on the sidebar and for the recent-links page only echo the current month. The code below displays the sidebar properly

```
<?php if (!is_page('48')) { ?>
                    <aside id="meta" class="widget">
                    <h1 class="widget-title">Link Log</h1>
                    <?php if ($links = rp_recentlinks_home()) {  ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($links as $link) { ?>

   <b><li><a href="<?php echo $link->link_url; ?>"><?php echo wptexturize($link->link_text); ?></a></b>
    <?php if ('' != $link->link_caption) { ?>&#8594;
    <?php echo wptexturize(convert_smilies($link->link_caption)); ?><?php } ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link->link_permalink; ?>"></a></li>

    <?php } ?>

</ul>
<?php } ?>
                </aside>
                <?php } ?>
```

and this code display the actual recent-links page

```
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php rp_recentlinks_archive_header(); ?></h1>
                    </header>

<div class="entry-content">
    <?php $links = rp_recentlinks_archive_page(); ?>
</div>
    <?php if ($links) {  ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($links as $link) { ?>

            <p id="rlink-<?php echo $link->ID; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $link->link_url; ?>"><?php echo wptexturize($link->link_text); ?></a>
            <?php if ('' != $link->link_caption) { ?>&#8594;
            <?php echo wptexturize(convert_smilies($link->link_caption)); ?><?php } ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $link->link_permalink; ?>" class="permalink"></a></p>



        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

I tried putting the following code in the body.

```
$list = array_slice($input, 0, 5); // $list now only having first 5 item.
```

But I don't know how to apply it, if that's the command at all. So perhaps, someone can guide in the right direction. Thanks in advance, Jorge.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you have to add is this before you pass `$links` to the `foreach` loop:

```
$links = array_slice($links,0,5);
```